# Is there a newer version of NSPersistentDocument Core Data Tutorial for Mac OS X v10.4?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, nspersistentdocument

I found a [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial104/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial104.pdf) about NSPersistentDocument, which was out-dated. The document is titled [NSPersistentDocument Core Data Tutorial for Mac OS X v10.4](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial104/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial104.pdf). Is there any other newer version of the document? Or, is there alternative to this kind of tutorial?

Comment: `NSPersistentDocument` has barely changed since 10.4. In what way is the tutorial not working?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I just wonder whether there are other updated one since we have some changes in Objective-C [link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405) for a new learner of Xcode and Objective-C like me.  I want to hear what people have to say about this.  I might have to wait until I could have some level of knowledge in Xcode and Objective-C to use that tutorial then.

Comment: There are new things in Objective-C, but the older styles still work. At the language level, nothing has been removed or even deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will use that tutorial. It is good to know that I am not reading an outdated material when there is an updated one.

Comment: Still, CoreData changed quite a lot, and added new concurrency scheme and much more. Nothing in the old tutorial tells you how to integrate reasonably with the new CoreData.

Comment: The link from Apple has long been marked as **retired** and has been removed since then. Apparently the referred outdated document is only available by [docplayer.net](https://docplayer.net/5046271-Nspersistentdocument-core-data-tutorial-for-mac-os-x-v10-4-retired-document.html). To me, the original question is still valid as it is very difficult to find documentation as I am trying to implement `NSPersistentDocument` today on OSX 10.13.